# Exporting the json document for the whole project in firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I export the json document for the whole project in Firestore database, this is possible for the realtime database, but I cannot find this option for the Firestore database. I need this document to analyze why my document is exceeding the limit size, which is 1 MB.
I am having this error when trying to add something to the document :
"firebase error document cannot be written because its size exceeds 1 MB"

PS. The document is being accessed by many users simultaneously, and we are registering the modifications commands in the Firestore database.

Comment: If you using Android, then I think [this](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android) might help.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for your answer. No I am using it in a nodejs application, is there any known command or api that can help me to download this file as a json file ?

Comment: Isn't that just calling `data()` on your document snapshot?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about programming per se.

Comment: Originally it is a programming problem, the goal is to debug the document size limit error, it is exceeding 1mb without containing 160 kb of data in the document.

Answer (score 1):

There is no UI element to export a document's data from Firestore in the Firebase console.

There is a page to [import and export data](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export) in the Cloud console, but that one works on an entire collection or larger, not on an individual document, and the output will not be the simple JSON that I think you are looking for.

The easiest way to get the JSON of a single document is through the API, by calling `data()` on the `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Normally, getData() should return the whole document, however, for a reason that I am not aware of, the returned file has a size much smaller than 1 MB (about 160kb)! while at the same time I am getting the same "firebase error document cannot be written because its size exceeds 1 MB"... I know this may deviate the subject of the post a little, but do you have an explanation of this difference in the size between what I extracted via the getData on DocumentSnapshot and the size calculation done by firebase ?

Comment: I always assumed (but never checked) Firestore uses this table to determine the size of a document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

Comment: Even with this table, which mainly calculate string sizes as the number of UTF-8 encoded bytes + 1, the difference I have is still not explainable. I will try this library to calculate the size and post the result here, if I get an explanation. https://github.com/alekslario/firestore-size